# How to add listeners to SplitPane Divider positions?

Tags: listener, javafx-8, splitpane

I can't figure out how to listen for a "Divider Repositioned" event on a JavaFX 8 SplitPane.  Here is a simple working Application that just needs the event listener added.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

```
public class TestCase extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane leftPane = new Pane();
        Pane rightPane = new Pane();
        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(leftPane, rightPane);

        // Need to create a listener that fires whenever the SplitPane's Divider is repositioned
        // Within this listener I need access to the leftPane and rightPane so I can call requestLayout()

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(splitPane));
        primaryStage.setWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to request the layout when the divider moves: that should happen automatically (because the size of the panes change). Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm trying to troubleshoot a bug in my application that has something to do with resizing the panes within the SplitPane.  However, in order to troubleshoot it I need to know how to "listen" for the divider position being changed.  Once I get that figured out I can continue troubleshooting my **actual** problem.

Comment: Why not to use more specific layout other than Pane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the dividers with `splitPane.getDividers()` and add ChangeListeners to the `dividers.positionProperty()`.